# Avoid asInstanceOf in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I have something like this now:

```
object Shared {
  trait Foo {
    type T <: Foo
    def +(other: T): T
  }

  case class IntFoo(value: Int) extends Foo {
    type T = IntFoo
    def +(other: IntFoo): IntFoo = IntFoo(this.value + other.value)
  }
}

object Current extends App {
  import Shared._

  case class Bar(foo: Foo) {
    def +(other: Bar): Bar = Bar(foo + other.foo.asInstanceOf[foo.T])
  }

  val bar1 = Bar(IntFoo(2))
  val bar2 = Bar(IntFoo(3))
  val expected = Bar(IntFoo(5))
  require(bar1 + bar2 == expected)
  println("All OK")
}
```

This works but requires an unsafe`asInstanceOf` that I'd like to eliminate with as little disturbance to the code as possible.

I'd like the compiler to catch invalid code such as:

```
  val otherBar = Bar(StringFoo("asdf"))
  val invalidSum = bar1 + otherBar // this throws ClassCastException in runtime
```

I tried the following:

```
  case class Bar[FooT <: Foo](foo: FooT) {
    def +(other: Bar[FooT]): Bar[FooT] = {
      Bar(foo + other.foo)
    }
  }
```

but I'm getting

```
Error:(35, 27) type mismatch;
 found   : other.foo.type (with underlying type FooT)
 required: Bar.this.foo.T
      Bar(foo + other.foo)
                ^
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `Foo.+` takes a value of `Foo`'s internal type `T`. So you have to specify in your `Bar.+`, that `other` has that same internal type `T`. You can do it with a dependent type:

```
case class Bar[FooT <: Foo](foo: FooT) {
  def +(other: Bar[foo.T]): Bar[foo.T] = {
    Bar(foo + other.foo)
  }
}
```

The result will be `Bar[foo.T]` as well, because `foo.T` is what `Foo.+` returns by definition.

Anyway, this works with the `IntFoo` example, and gives a compile error with the `StringFoo` example.

Comment: This works, although IntelliJ highlights it as an error.

Answer (score 1):

This should behave correctly, presuming you are happy with how things are typed:

```
object Shared {
  trait Foo[T <: Foo[T]] {
    def +(other: T): T
  }

  case class IntFoo(value: Int) extends Foo[IntFoo] {
    def +(other: IntFoo): IntFoo = IntFoo(this.value + other.value)
  }
}

object Current extends App {
  import Shared._

  case class Bar[T <: Foo[T]](foo: T) {
    def +(other: Bar[T]): Bar[T] = Bar(foo + other.foo)  
  }

  val bar1 = Bar(IntFoo(2))
  val bar2 = Bar(IntFoo(3))
  val expected = Bar(IntFoo(5))
  require(bar1 + bar2 == expected)
  println("All OK")
}
```

Comment: I'd just add a reference to F-bounded polymorphism (to help readers understand the constraint `T <: Foo[T]` and its implications): https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded

Comment: I'm not very happy to change the typing of Foo because it is used in a bazillion places without any type parameter (just as `foo: Foo`) and changing them to `foo: Foo[_]` there will be a lot of changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Bar[+F <: Foo](foo: F) {
  def +(other: Bar { type T = foo.T }): Bar =
    Bar(foo + other.foo)
}
```

Comment: Getting `Type mismatch, expected: Bar.this.foo.T, actual F.`